# How to access coloumn values from active record object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(1)
```

I want to access the name of the user from this object; how do I do it?

```
@user.name  # Gives Error = No mathod 'name'
```

Comment: do you have column Name in table Users in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `User.find` instead of `User.find_by_id` and then perform `.name` on that, you should receive your output.

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.name
```

But from not seeing your entire DB, it might be you're simply getting a no method because the field does not exist. In that case you should change the method name accordingly from:

```
@user.name # to ->
@user.first_name # or whatever the field is actually called
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`@user = User.find(1)`

then

```
@user.name
```

find_by_id returns multiple records so you'd have to do

```
@user.first.name
```

if you use find_by_id

Comment: Can I user @user.name in the view directly as <%= @user.name %> to display it ?

Comment: If you define it as `@user` in the controller, you can.

Comment: I think _find_by_id_ only returns one record. For multiple records, there's _find_all_by_id_